# Grails Spring Security Plugin- Want to create Project specific User's roles?

Tags: security, spring, plugins, grails

I have domain Classes "Project" and "User"  and need to implement authentication using Spring Secutity plugin.

The default implementation of this plugin provides us to create ROLES that are User specific. But in my project I need to create Project specific ROLES for the USER and need to authenticate them.

e.g. User-A can be an ADMIN in Project-1
and User-A can be MODERATOR in Project-2
also User-A could be MEMBER in Project-3

Is it possible to have this type of authentication system using spring security plugin?

PS: I saw this thread in the mailing list but got only a vague idea.  http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-Plugin-change-the-process-that-grants-access-td2539915.html

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can name the Roles whatever you want so Project_1_Admin, Project_2_Admin are acceptable names to use. I dont think a multi-tenant solution is what you are looking for based on the wording of your question.